# Использовать введённые строку в качестве параметра для команды SQL

Tags: python, sql

Можно-ли сделать так, чтобы введённая строка через функцию *input* была использована в качестве параметра для команды базе данных SQL?

(*Что-то по типу "Присвоили переменной l2 значение "ый" и команда для SQL будет выглядеть как: "SELECT * FROM adjectives LIKE %ый", а не "SELECT * FROM adjectives LIKE %l2""*)

```
connect = pymysql.Connect(

)

l2 = input("Введите слово: ")
condition = l2.isalpha()

if condition == True:
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM adjectives WHERE word = %s", (l2,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connect.close()

    for i in data:
        print(str(i))
```

При попытке запуска ничего не происходит (прикладываю часть таблицы БД и результат кода:

[image: Таблица БД]

[image: Результат кода]

Comment: `    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM adjectives WHERE word = %s", (l2,))`

Comment: Переделал вопрос. Ошибка не выскакивает, но ничего не происходит при этом при вводе тех же данных через консоль появляются столбцы м данными